How do I take a text from .txt file and use it in html?
So, I did this in my html code:
<script>
    let saveFile = () => {
        const search = document.getElementById('search');
        const email = document.getElementById('email');
        const password = document.getElementById('password');
        const tel = document.getElementById('tel');
        const check = document.getElementById('check');
        
        let data = 
            '\r search: ' + search.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'email: ' + email.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'password: ' +password.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'tel: ' + tel.value + ' \r\n ' +
            'check: ' + check.value + ' \r\n ';
        
        const textToBLOB = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
        const sFileName = 'data.txt';

        let newLink = document.createElement("a");
        newLink.download = sFileName;

        if (window.webkitURL != null) {
            newLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
        }
        else {
            newLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
            newLink.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(newLink);
        }

        newLink.click(); 
    }
</script>

I am showing you this code, which takes the values from the inputs and puts them into a .txt file that is downloaded, so you see what I used. I do not know if it is needed, but just to be safe. After the .txt file with the values downloads, I want to read the text from the downloaded file into my other html code. It has no real purpose, so that is why I want to do it like this. IT IS JUST FOR FUN. That is why I want to read the text, into the html code instead just taking the values. I am just curious.

Why do you want to read the text file? Read the user inputs search.value, email.value, password.value, tel.value and check.value.

What do you mean by "take from"? What do you mean by "use in"? And, if you already have code that gives you the values, and you want to have code that uses the values somewhere else... why not just put that code where the values are created? What use is the file?

Please do not tag questions with obviously unrelated languages. There is no PHP code here and no reason why PHP would be relevant to solving the problem.

The short answer to the question, if it is possible, is yes. The issue in your question is that we don't know the use case. Your question will probably be closed because it is too unfocused. You present code that works and is not related to the question.

hi there actally the error you are seeing data back from the .txt file into an HTML documents because when you are reading  the process is going to be a little complex due to browser security.they are designed like this so web pages cant access files.
to achieve the functionality you can use   which will let the user to select the file
example

Load

Due to security concerns directly loading files from a script is forbidden.
The only way to achieve what you want is to ask the user for some input file with an input to let him choose the file he wants to upload.

You can maybe try also searching about the script "type="module"" attribute which can allow the script to perform some operations a "normal" script cannot.
